# Nvidia Drivers differences

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

What is the difference between

1. NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
2. NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS
3. NVIDIA headless metapackage

Im trying to install Nvidia driver on my ubuntu 20.04 but I don't know which to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An open source driver called `nouveau`. It is used by default and doesn't need installation.
2. A proprietary driver provided as a binary `deb` built for every kernel update.
3. A proprietary driver with kernel code provided as a source code that is being built on every kernel update using `dkms` technology.

If you want a proprietary Nvidia driver, you can use one of 2, or 3rd. It is a matter of opinions which one is "better". It the same driver provided version is same.