# Choosing which nvidia drivers to install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

What the differences in these nvidia drivers?

1. nvidia metapackage
2. nvidia headless metapackage - is this the one with `dkms`? if yes what is `dkms`?
3. nvidia headless metapackage no dkms
4. nvidia xorg - is this the one that is open source? is this `nouveau`?

I know this seem duplicate of [Nvidia Drivers differences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370692/nvidia-drivers-differences), but I find four "types" of nvidia drivers to choose from

I don't know how to choose or what should I consider when choosing in these drivers

Comment: so are you asking what the first one is? because 2-4 are clearly explained in the answer you linked.

Comment: Okay, what the first one is? how it differ to others? should I choose the one with `dkms`?